# Print random numbers on same line inside f string

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I'm trying to generate random numbers onto the same line and I am having some issues with the formatting.

I am trying to shorten my long code below into something more efficient code wise:

```py
import random

randomnumber1 = random.randint(1,99)
randomnumber2 = random.randint(1,99)
randomnumber3 = random.randint(1,99)
randomnumber4 = random.randint(1,99)
randomnumber5 = random.randint(1,99)
randomnumber6 = random.randint(1,99)
lucky_numbers = f"{randomnumber1}-{randomnumber2}-{randomnumber3}-{randomnumber4}-{randomnumber5}-[{randomnumber6}]"
print(lucky_numbers)
```

Output is this:

```py
31-29-31-50-69-[14]
```

After a few attempts, my new code is this:

```py
for i in range(5):
    first_half=print(f"{random.randint(1,99)}-", end="")
print(f"{first_half}-[{random.randint(1,99)}]")
```

However, whenever I run it the output is this:

```py
77-41-39-32-74-None-[29]
```

How do I stop the '`None`' from appearing in my output and also why is it appearing? Thanks

Comment: Remove the print call from inside the for loop

Comment: what is the meaning of `first_half=print(f"{random.randint(1,99)}-", end="")`. It is wrong usage. You can define `first_half=f"{random.randint(1,99)}-"`and print in for loop

Comment: `first_half=print(...)` The print function returns none; it does not return what was printed.  So first_half is none.

Comment: I would first create a list of numbers with `numbers = [random.randint(1, 99) for _ in range(6)]` and the print it with `print(f"{'-'.join(map(str, numbers[:-1]))}-[{numbers[-1]}]")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assign `print` to `first_half` and `print` return `None`. You can use `'-'.join`.

```
first_half = '-'.join(str(random.randint(1,99)) for _ in range(5))
print(f"{first_half}-[{random.randint(1,99)}]")
```

---

```
63-55-77-71-81-[47]
```

Explanation:

```
# list comprehension
>>> [str(random.randint(1,99)) for _ in range(5)]
['94', '7', '15', '86', '54']

# use '-'.join()
>>> '-'.join(str(random.randint(1,99)) for _ in range(5))
'94-7-15-86-54'
```

Answer (score 1):

a bit shorter:

```
from random import choices

>>> '{}-{}-{}-{}-{}-[{}]'.format(*choices(range(1,100), k=6))

'79-48-93-81-18-[72]'
```